# ListView of Child Fragment is not refreshing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am using `nested-fragment` and inside my `parent fragment`, there is a `child fragment` containing a `listview`. I put the parent fragment in `backStack` and when I resume it, the `listview` is not recreating/refreshing. Rather than the same `listItem` is appending below.
This is the code how I add `child fragment` in `parent fragment`:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, chapterFragment); // chapterFragment is declared and initialized globally in the class
        transaction.commit();
}
```

And this is my child Fragment:

```
public class ChaptersListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.size(); i++) {
            items.add(CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(i).chapterTitle);
        }
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(),
                R.layout.list_layout, items);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

I tried `notifyDataSetChanged()` also. But nothing made my code working.